# pull content from xml files in php and parse it into table rows

Tags: php, xml

I have a directory called `incoming_folder` in which there are some xml files **(36017P.xml, 36031P.xml, and hello.xml)** in it.

```
<?php
$src_dir    = 'incoming_folder';  /* Place where xml files are present */
$xml_files = preg_grep('~\.(xml)$~', scandir($src_dir));
print_r($xml_files);              /* Line#A */

Line#A display the following o/p:

Array ( [3] => 36017P.xml [5] => 36031P.xml [7] => hello.xml )

$xml=simplexml_load_file("incoming_folder") or die('Unable to load XML');                                      

$path_program_en = $xml->xpath('//StringAssetInfo/attrName[text()="CASE_SERIES_TITLE"]/..');
$path_title_en = $xml->xpath('//StringAssetInfo/attrName[text()="CASE_EPISODE_TITLE"]/..');
$path_description_en = $xml->xpath('//TextAssetInfo/attrName[text()="CASE_DESCRIPTION_ENGLISH"]/..');
?>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that it pull the sub-elements **CASE_SERIES_TITLE, CASE_EPISODE_TITLE, and CASE_DESCRIPTION_ENGLISH**
values from their respective xmls **36017P.xml, 36031P.xml, and hello.xml**  and parse it in the table rows.

`Program (EN)` `Title (EN)`  `Description (EN)`

**CASE_SERIES_TITLE, CASE_EPISODE_TITLE, and CASE_DESCRIPTION_ENGLISH** sub-elements are present in **every xml (36017P.xml, 36031P.xml, and hello.xml)**

```
<tr>
    <th style="width:8%;" >Program (EN)</th>
    <th style="width:8%;" >Title (EN)</th>
    <th style="width:8%;" >Description (EN)</th>
</tr>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo $path_program_en; ?></td>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo $path_title_en;  ?></td>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo $path_description_en; ?></td>
</tr>
```

The snippet of content from `36017P.xml` is:

```
<StringAssetInfo>
   <attrName>CASE_SERIES_TITLE</attrName>
   <attrTagName>CASE_SERIES_TITLE</attrTagName>
   <value>PrimeTime Politics</value>
</StringAssetInfo>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample XML file contents to the question, it can help to make the result more reliable.

Comment: @NigelRen Added. Please have a look.

Comment: Is that sample data complete or are there repeats of this data with another level above this?

Comment: There are no repeats for that `<attrName>CASE_SERIES_TITLE</attrName>`, `<attrTagName>CASE_SERIES_TITLE</attrTagName>` and   `<value>PrimeTime Politics</value>`. It is unique in the whole xml.

Comment: OK - but are there levels of the XML above these (i.e. a root node) are these grouped under another node?

Comment: @NigelRen This is the [xml](http://jsfiddle.net/cf06j4ex/1/). I know I should not be putting in the fiddle.

Comment: I will have a look and get back to you.

Comment: @NigelRen Technically this `$path_program_en = $xml->xpath('//StringAssetInfo/attrName[text()="CASE_SERIES_TITLE"]/..');` should pull from every xmls `(36017P.xml, 36031P.xml, and hello.xml)`  and parse it into table rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code builds up a list of the data extracted from each file, so after the loop `$programs` contains each files information.

I've modified the XPath expressions to make them easier to use and as it is possible that any item may be missing (you can remove this bit if you are sure they will be there) it uses

```
(string)($path_program_en[0]??"")
```

So the `??` bit will make sure there is some data to use and the `(string)` makes sure it's a string (and not a SimpleXMLElement).

Once built up, again another loop to build the table up...

```
$programs = [];
foreach ( $xml_files as $file ) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

    $path_program_en = $xml->xpath('//StringAssetInfo[attrName="CPAC_SERIES_TITLE"]/value');
    $path_title_en = $xml->xpath('//StringAssetInfo[attrName="CPAC_EPISODE_TITLE"]/value');
    $path_description_en = $xml->xpath('//TextAssetInfo[attrName="CPAC_DESCRIPTION_ENGLISH"]/value');

    $programs[] = [ "series_title" => (string)($path_program_en[0]??""), 
        "episode_title" => (string)($path_title_en[0]??""), 
        "description" => (string)($path_description_en[0]??"")];
}

echo '<tr>
<th style="width:8%;" >Program (EN)</th>
<th style="width:8%;" >Title (EN)</th>
<th style="width:8%;" >Description (EN)</th>
</tr>';

foreach ( $programs as $program)    {
    echo '<tr>
             <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;">'.$program["series_title"].'</td>
             <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;">'.$program["episode_title"].'</td>
            <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;">'.$program["description"].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Note: Please make sure the element names are correct - as I couldn't find `CASE_SERIES_TITLE` in the sample XML you have.

Edit:

For older versions of PHP use..

```
$programs = array();
foreach ( $xml_files as $file ) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

    $path_program_en = $xml->xpath('//StringAssetInfo[attrName="CPAC_SERIES_TITLE"]/value');
    $path_title_en = $xml->xpath('//StringAssetInfo[attrName="CPAC_EPISODE_TITLE"]/value');
    $path_description_en = $xml->xpath('//TextAssetInfo[attrName="CPAC_DESCRIPTION_ENGLISH"]/value');

    $path_program_en = isset($path_program_en[0])?$path_program_en[0]:"";
    $path_title_en = isset($path_title_en[0])?$path_title_en[0]:"";
    $path_description_en = isset($path_description_en[0])?$path_description_en[0]:"";

    $programs[] = array( "series_title" => (string)$path_description_en, 
        "episode_title" => (string)$path_title_en, 
        "description" => (string)$path_description_en);
}
```

Comment: Just checking whats inside `$xml_files` ?

Comment: Should I be doing something like this `$xm_files=simplexml_load_file("incoming_folder") or die('Unable to load XML');`

Comment: `$xml_files` is the result of your `preg_grep`

Comment: I am getting error at line `$programs = [];` I am wondering what can be the reason.

Comment: Try `$programs = array();`

Comment: is there any other place I need to make changes ? I am still some error. I am also figuring out on my own.

Comment: No idea, do you get any output?  Does `print_r($programs);` give anything.

Comment: It is showing this `Array ( )`  I meant to say after that line.

Comment: I did some debugging and added these lines `print_r($file);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file)  or die('Unable to load XML');` I got the following o/p:

`36017P.xmlUnable to load XML`

Comment: Looks as though you need to add `$src_dir`, so `$xml = simplexml_load_file($src_dir."/".$file);`

Comment: Now, its not going inside this     `$programs[] = [ "series_title" => (string)($path_program_en[0]??""), 
        "episode_title" => (string)($path_title_en[0]??""), 
        "description" => (string)($path_description_en[0]??"")];` Investigating what is the issue.

Comment: Try the second version of the code in the answer - the original used some PHP 7 code.

Comment: For older versions of php, Its not going inside this `$programs[] = [ "series_title" => (string)$path_description_en, 
        "episode_title" => (string)$path_title_en, 
        "description" => (string)$path_description_en];`

Comment: And it was the issue with 1st version of code as well.

Comment: Changed the syntax to `$programs[] = array( "seri` (check the updated answer for the full line)

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430459/how-to-convert-mp4-files-into-mp3-on-button-click-using-ffmpeg-php). Its not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.